# .on() event handler inside ajaxComplete()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this:

```
$('.task').on('click', function()
{
    task_id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log('Task id: ' + task_id);
});
```

But this doesn't work as it should when the content is reloaded via ajax. `task_id` value stays the same even after clicking different elements after the ajax reload. Apparently I have to bind it to the `body` first.

This is how it is in my code right now though (it works as expected):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    $('.task').on('click', function()
    {
        task_id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log('Task id: ' + task_id);
    });
});
```

But I've been told this duplicates/doubles the trigger for the `.on('click')` event? Is this true? How do I know then when to bind to the direct selector or bind to the `document.body` instead?
Which would be more efficient? Binding to `body` or putting the event delegation inside `ajaxComplete()`?

I'm a little confused too since I have other event handlers inside the same `.js` file but outside `ajaxComplete()` that seem to work just fine even after an ajax reload?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you include `$.ajax()` call at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 It's just the performance with which I'm more concerned.

Comment: What do you mean by "performance"?

Comment: You can refer following post for more info: http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/

Comment: @guest271314 like perhaps which would be the better way to do it for faster loading of elements

Comment: _"like perhaps which would be the better way to do it for faster loading of elements"_ How is  "faster loading of elements" related to text at original Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm just confused since I discovered two ways to do it and I'm not sure which would be the better way to go. Binding to `body` or using `ajaxComplete()`. I've been told before that putting `.on` inside `ajaxComplete()` duplicates the trigger.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve at `.ajaxComplete()` call? Are `.task` elements appended into `document` at `$.ajax()` call?

Comment: @guest271314 Do you mean like in general, in my code? Nothing in particular, really. The other `.on` event handlers are outside `ajaxComplete()` but for this one I have to either bind it to `body` or put it inside `ajaxComplete()` for it to work since the involved html content are dynamically loaded. Honestly, not sure why.

Comment: @guest271314 And yes, `.task` elements are loaded to the `document` via `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method with [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach, when generating elements dynamically(content is updated via `$.ajax()`)/manipulating selectors. then you won't need to attach event handler in `ajaxComplete()`

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$(document).on('click', '.task', function(){
    //Rest of your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: great knowledge sharing. +1

Comment: Sweet. So much clearer now. Thanks! Just a follow-up question though, so putting the handler inside `ajaxComplete()` is less efficient?

Comment: @herondale, Yes its less  efficient.  When you perform `$(element).on('event',callback_function)` if you have 10 element then 10 event handlers are attached. when using Event Delegation you are binding only 1 event handler with parent